# django rest framework multiple url arguments

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In rest api view I need to have 2 objects. For example:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    ....

class Bar(models.Model):
    ....
```

What is correct way to get them? I mean how should I configure urls? I think this is not really good practice: `url(r'^foo/(?P<pk>\d+)/bar/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', FooBarView.as_view())`
Or: `url(r'^foobar/$', FooBarView.as_view())` and then pass parameters: `?foo=1&bar=2`.

Comment: the objects have any relationship?

Comment: They are related but not directly. `class FooBar(models.Model)` has 2 foreign keys to each `Foo` and `Bar` classes.

Comment: what do you want to do with that view?

Comment: I need to display `FooBar`. In that view will be some kind of navigation for navigating to `Foo` and `Bar`.

Comment: I will do filtering based on `Foo` and `Bar` and get results of `FooBar`

Comment: for filtering you should use parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is more like a design problem.

Which one is better? I will say it depends on what is the relationship between model foo and model bar.

If you get model **Class** and model **student**, and you want to get student info and base on which class and relative student_number, like each class will have a student no.1.

you can go:

```
url(r'^class/(?P<class_pk>\d+)/student/(?P<student_pk>\d+)/$')
```

If you want to get both model information, but you want put them into a statistic table,

you can go:

```
url(r'^statistic/$')
```

then pass parameters like:

```
 ?class=1&student=2
```

These are just simple examples, there should be other cases, and you should use other way to design your URL API.

Answer (score 0):

For django >= 1.5 You could pass parameters to class view doing somethin like this:

```
class Foo(TemplateView):
    template_name = "yourtemplatesdir/template.html"
    # Set any other attributes here 

    # dispatch is called when the class instance loads
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.id = kwargs.get('foo_id', "other_def_id")
        self.barid = kwargs.get('bar_id', "other_def_id")

# depending on your definition, this class might be different 

class Bar(TemplateView):
    template_name = "yourtemplatesdir/template.html"
    # Set any other attributes here 

    # this method might not be necessary
    # dispatch is called when the class instance loads
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.id = kwargs.get('bar_id', "other_def_id")
```

In your url conf something like:

```
from .views import FooBar

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(
        regex=r'^(?P<foo_id>\d+)/(?P<bar_id>\d+)/$'
        view=FooBar.as_view(),
        name='viewname'
    ),
)
```

Then, in your template view for FooBar, you could do:

```
{{ view.id }}
{{ view.barid }}
```

I hope it helps, it could be more detailed if you provide further information about the object information needed in your '*action*'.